# Can I glue the X axis to the Y axis?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Consider the following diagram of algebraic varieties:

$$\mathbb{A}^0 \to \mathbb{A}^1 \rightrightarrows \mathbb{A}^2$$

Here the first arrow is the inclusion of the origin into the line, and the next two are the inclusion of the line into the plane as the X and the Y axes.

> Does this diagram have a colimit in the category of schemes?

(The first arrow giving inclusion of the point is not relevant; it just so happens that it was there when I met this question.)

Comment: I think the question you really meant to ask (given the title) is more likely this: “what is the colimit $C$ of the diagram $\mathbb{A}^1 \leftarrow \mathbb{A}^0 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ (where both arrows take the point to the origin) in the category of schemes — and what is the morphism $C\to\mathbb{A}^2$ produced when applying the universal property of $C$ to the two morphisms $\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{A}^2$ taking the line to the $x$ and $y$ axes?”, isn't it?

Comment: No, I meant the question as asked: take the plane, and try to glue the entire X axis to the entire Y axis.

Comment: Ah, so you basically want to know whether $\operatorname{Spec} R$ where $R := \{f\in k[x,y] \colon f(t,0)=f(0,t)\}$ works as a colimit in the category of schemes (it is the colimit in the category of affine schemes).

Comment: Good point, and I guess that would have to work.  Does that ring have a more reasonable name?  Is it finitely generated?

Comment: It is finitely generated because it contains the ring of symmetric polynomials $S:=k[x+y,xy]$, and $k[x,y]$ is a finite module over $S$. After a quick check, I think $R$ is generated by $xy^2$ as an $S$-algebra.

Comment: I remember thinking about the somewhat similar question of collapsing the $x$ axis to a point, and the ring is then not noetherian, but that's as far as I can say without thinking more carefully.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly You are correct. More precisely, as an $S$-module, $R$ is free with generators $1$ and $xy(x-y)$. Proof: If $f(x,y) \in R$, let $f_+ = (f(x,y)+f(y,x))/2$ and $f_- = (f(x,y) - f(y,x))/2$. Then $f = f_+ + f_-$. Clearly, $f_+ \in S$. Also clearly, $f_-$ is divisible by $xy(x-y)$, and $f_- / (xy(x-y))$ is in $S$.

Comment: PS: I've become convinced there are too many answers being left in comments so, if no one else gets around to turning this into an answer in the next day or so, I'll write up a CW version.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer +1 for volunteering to write up an actual answer. Anecdotally, I feel that a culture has been developing on MO \of "short answers belong in the comments" which I disagree with and find rather annoying.

Comment: @TimothyChow I agree that answers should be posted as answers. But here we have a short *partial* answer. It is unclear to me whether $\mathrm{Spec} (R)$ is a pushout w.r.t. all (not necessarily affine) varieties, and it is an interesting part of the question.

Comment: As an aside, I asked Macaulay 2 for an equation for the surface with coordinate ring $R = k[xy, x+y, xy^2]$, it is $a^3 + c^2 = abc$ where $a=xy$, $b = x+y$, $c=x^2 y$.  And here you can see the surface for yourself: https://www.math3d.org/6cuumoSv

Answer (score 29, accepted):

We can rewrite the coequalizer as the pushout of the diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
    X & \to & \mathbb A^2 \\
    \downarrow & & \\
    \mathbb A^1 & &  \\
\end{array}
$$
where $X$ is the union of the $x$- and $y$-axis, and the vertical map quotients by the involution swapping the two components.

The category of affine schemes has all pushouts: they are given by fibered product of coordinate rings. But a pushout in the category of affine schemes is not necessarily a pushout in the category of all schemes. A sufficient condition for a pushout of affine schemes to be a pushout in the category of schemes can be found in a paper of Karl Schwede ("Gluing schemes and a scheme without closed points", Theorem 3.4): it suffices that one leg of the pushout is a closed immersion. So we are fine.

As noted by Gro-Tsen in a comment, the pushout can be written explicitly as $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ where $R = \{ f \in k[x,y] : f(t,0)=f(0,t)\}$.

Comment: Which leg of the pushout is a closed immersion?

Comment: The horizontal leg: $X$ is here $V(xy) \subset \mathbb A^2$, not the disjoint union of the two axes. But you are right that if you directly translate the coequalizer to a pushout you get $\mathbb A^1 \sqcup \mathbb A^1$ rather than $X$ in the upper corner, and a (small) additional argument is needed for why the pushout is the same.

Answer (score 6):

Dan Petersen has already answered the hard part -- how to show that the affine pushout $\{ f \in k[x,y] : f(t,0) = f(0,t) \}$ is also the scheme push out. I write to record a discussion in the comments about how to see that this ring is finitely generated and obtain an explicit list of generators.

Let $R = k[x,y]$ and let $S = k[x,y]^{S_2} = k[b,c]$ where $b=x+y$ and $c = xy$. Let $A = \{ f \in k[x,y] : f(t,0) = f(0,t) \}$. Then clearly $A$ is an $S$-submodule of $R$. Since $S$ is noetherian and $R$ is generated as an $S$-module by $1$ and $x$, this shows that $A$ is finitely generated as an $S$-module.

If the characteristic of $k$ is not $2$, one can get explicit generators easily. $A$ is invariant under switching the generators $x$ and $y$, so $A$ splits into positive and negative eigenspaces, call them $A_+$ and $A_-$, for this switch. The positive eigenspace is just $S$. The negative eigenspace $A_-$ is $xy(x-y) S$, since it is easy to see that anything in $A_-$ is divisibly by $xy(x-y)$, and the quotient is in $A_+$. So $A = S \oplus xy(x-y) S$ and the ring is generated by $b = x+y$, $c = xy$ and $f=xy(x-y)$, with the defining relation $f^2 = c^2 (b^2-4c)$.

Comment: A generating set that works uniformly in characteristic $2$ is $x+y, xy, x^2y$: to get $x^a y^b$ for all $a,b>0$ it suffices to handle the case when $b=1$ and $a=1$. The case $b=1$ follows by induction since $x^a y = (x+y) x^{a-1} y + (x^2y) x^{a-2}$ and the case $a=1$ follows by symmetry since $xy^2 = xy (x+y)-x^2y$.  This has defining relation (with the same $b,c$ and with $g=x^2y$)  $g^2 = c ( b g - c^2)$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't check the comments - this was pointed out (without proof) by Laurent Moret-Bailly and the equation was found by Vivek Shende.